# No ad config, Error code 3. for both live and test ads, after setting up app-ads.txt

Tags: android, admob, ads

My test ads and live ads was working fine. Until we setup app-ads.txt to our main URL, and its now verified. Our multiple devices are listed as test device in admob and also specified test ID in code. But nothing works. I tried to generate the release app and put it in open testing beta in play console but still not even a single ad appears and we still receive "No ad config" error.
Even the official test ads ids are now displaying " No ad config"
Please help!